# Angle from 2x2 Rotation Matrix

Tags: matrices, rotations

How would I go about extracting the angle from a 2x2 rotational matrix? I'm using a matrix to track transformations in 2D space, but I'm struggling to figure out how to reverse this once I've got the rotation matrix so I can just see the angle that was applied.

Answer (score 5):

If it's a 2D rotation matrix, then it equals
[$$R(\theta)=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\
\sin\theta & \cos \theta
\end{pmatrix}$$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)
where $\theta$ is the angle you are looking for. 
Therefore, you can simply take $\cos^{-1}$ of the first entry in your matrix.

Due to the periodicity of the cosine function though, you won't know the sign of $\theta$ (i.e., whether it is clockwise or anticlockwise). You can determine this by noting the signs of the sines (e.g. if the angle is $-30^\circ$, then the $\sin$ entry in the first column would be negative).

Comment: Note that that's not the complete answer. You still need to distinguish between clockwise and anticlockwise. You can do that by looking at the sign of the off-diagonal entries.

Comment: I would use the atan2 function on the entries with $\cos$ and $\sin$, otherwise you can get the direction wrong: $$\cos\theta=\cos(-\theta)$$

Comment: You're right, let me edit my answer.

Comment: This looks like I what I'm looking for, thanks. What does @Andrei mean by the entries with cos and sin for atan2? There are two of each in the matrix.

Comment: The definition of tangent is $\tan\theta=\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$. The atan2 function takes two inputs, the cosine and the sine. So, in this case, use the two values in the first column.

Comment: @Incredidave In general, the columns of a matrix tell you where the vectors $\mathbf i=(1,0)$ and $\mathbf j=(0,1)$. In particular, if we read off the first column, we see that $R(\theta)$ maps $\mathbf i$ to $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$. To find the angle of rotation, we can therefore use the [$\operatorname{atan2}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function.